# Algorithm to optimise team composition

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Assume I have a game in which there are characters, each of which have a relative strength/weakness against another character. E.g. A is strong (+2) against B but weak against C (-1) and neutral against D (0). Think any video game - Overwatch etc., you name it.

Given a matrix M of size m x m, where m is the number of characters and M_{i,j} denotes the strength of player i against player j, M will have a 0 in the diagonals and the lower triangular matrix will be the inverse transpose of the upper diagonal (or vice versa, since it's a square matrix).

The question is: given such a matrix and a vector of opposing players O (say, [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 18], what is the best algorithm to return a vector V of players of equal length, so that we 
- maximise the sum M_{V_1, O_1}, M_{V_2, O_2}...M_{V_6, O_6}, and
- minimise the sum M_{O_1, V_1} + M_{O_2, V_1}, ... + M_{O_6, V_6}?

What would be a good and efficient *practical* approach to this, other than brute force testing? Genetic algos sound good at this point, but I think there is DEFINITELY something more efficient around.

Pseudocode answers appreciated, too.

Excuse the incoherence, I am working on very little sleep (reflected by my apparent interest in mathematically optimising a team).

Comment: This looks a lot like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem

Comment: Your objective function is not clear. Do you have multiple objectives?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Yes - in order.

Comment: There is some sort of symmetry in the matrix. Does the value of the maximum bear any relation to the value of the minimum? If M(i,j) = -M(j,i) I would presume that anything that maximises the maximum also minimises the minimum.

Comment: Some questions: (1) Why two parts in the objective? As the matrix is antisymmetric, ```sum(M[v0,o0] + M[v1,o1], ...) == -sum(M[o0,v0] + M[o1,v1], ...)``` holds (1:1 mapping). Therefore the joint-objective of maximizing A and minimizing B has the same value for each valid solution (=0). This is not right, yes? (2) When selecting N players v_0, v_1, v_2... how are these scores calculated? Is the score the sum of each pairings of player/opponent indexing the costs or is there only a 1:1 mapping. If it's a 1:1 mapping, how is the order defined? Maybe you should give a small example!